# PowerShell Runspaces, outputs and variables

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to understand Runspaces in PowerShell. I know about the `PoshRSJob-Module`, but I'd like to create my Runspace Jobs by myself.

This is my code, mostly taken out from this [blog](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/11/28/beginning-use-of-powershell-runspaces-part-3/):

```
$Computer = "somename"
[runspacefactory]::CreateRunspacePool() > $null
$SessionState = [System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.InitialSessionState]::CreateDefault()
$RunspacePool = [runspacefactory]::CreateRunspacePool(1,5)
$RunspacePool.Open()
1..2 | % {
    $PowerShell = [powershell]::Create()
    $PowerShell.RunspacePool = $RunspacePool
    $PowerShell.AddScript({
        param(
            $Computer
        )
        $Computer
    }) > $null
    $PowerShell.AddParameter($Computer)
    $Invoke = $PowerShell.BeginInvoke()
    while (!($Invoke.IsCompleted)) {sleep -Milliseconds 2}
    $Data = $PowerShell.EndInvoke($Invoke)
    Write-Host $Data -f Red
}
```

Three question are in my mind:

- Will I be able to return a Value in a Variable and use it for further use inside the script after finishing the Job?
- Why is my `$Data` Variable empty?
- In the Script I have so far, what is creating the following output? If I `$null` the invocation like this `$Invoke = $PowerShell.BeginInvoke() > $null`
  , the script doesn't work properly anymore and still creates this output

`Commands            : System.Management.Automation.PSCommand
Streams             : System.Management.Automation.PSDataStreams
InstanceId          : 3b91cfda-028e-4cec-9b6d-55bded5d9d3c
InvocationStateInfo : System.Management.Automation.PSInvocationStateInfo
IsNested            : False
HadErrors           : False
Runspace            : 
RunspacePool        : System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspacePool
IsRunspaceOwner     : False
HistoryString       :`

Comment: `$PowerShell.AddParameter($Computer)` -> `[void]$PowerShell.AddArgument($Computer)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand your first question.

For the second question, I think it's because you're using `$PowerShell.AddParameter($Computer)`.

Try `$PowerShell.AddArgument($Computer)` instead. `AddArgument` is for adding a value that gets implicitly (positionally) bound to a parameter. `AddParameter` is for adding a named parameter. The overload of `AddParameter` that takes just a `string` is for `[Switch]` parameters.

For your third question, I think it's `$RunspacePool.Open()` that's giving you that output.

When trying to determine these things, look for lines, especially with method calls, that have no left-hand assignment; so things you aren't assigning to a variable, as that's generally how these values get put into the output stream.